# File not found error in Xcode using Evernote iOS API in Swift with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, evernote

Everything seems to be fine until I started importing

```
import evernote_cloud_sdk_ios
```

then suddenly, I got an error

> "Could not build Objective-C module evernote_cloud_sdk_ios"

I have added and used another Objective-C library in my project and it worked fine, however Evernote SDK is seems to be the only one that I have a problem with.

So here is my pod file

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire' , '1.2.3'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'JGProgressHUD'
pod 'evernote-cloud-sdk-ios'

target 'HackerNote' do

end

target 'HackerNoteTests' do

end
```

And here is the error that I got from file "evernote-cloud-sdk-ios-umbrella.h"

[image]

However, every files specified in "evernote-cloud-sdk-ios-umbrella.h" are already inside the Pods directory

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've found "cannot build errors" can often occur if you are using Apple framework files - that the custom library relies on - from a different version of xCode. For example I had an issue building parse when including the parse sdk because I used the Apple maps Framework for 8.3 of xCode while running xCode 8.4.